# ES6 fetch return stament error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

The following returns "undefined" X 2 from:

countriesUrl is an array of objects.

```
        console.log(countriesURL2);
        console.log(carMakesUrl2);

        function getDataFromJSON(url){
            var dataJSON;
            fetch(countriesUrl).then(function(data) {
              if (data.ok) {
                data.json().then(function(data) {
                   dataJSON = data;
                   return dataJSON;
                });
              } 
            });
            return dataJSON;
        }

        function displayData(){
            var countriesURL2 = getDataFromJSON(countriesUrl);
            var carMakesUrl2 = getDataFromJSON(carMakesUrl);
            console.log(countriesURL2);
            console.log(carMakesUrl2);
        }

        displayData();
```

Why is "dataJSON" returned undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a promise, so everything inside your `then` function is run asynchronously. `dataJSON` is returned *before* it is set inside your promise.